# Разбить эксель таблицу на блоки

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, excel, openpyxl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо спарсить расписание занятий из excel файла. Структура файла максимально ужасная.
С помощью цикла прохожу по строкам и столбцам и достаю данные об уроке. Но как достать день недели? В день может быть и 8 и 10 уроков, то есть просто интервал задать не получится

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто считать дни недели по первому уроку, при условии, что уроки есть каждый день, или учебные дни в неделе постоянны. Встретил 1-ый урок - значит, наступил следующий день недели.